# Norm of a linear functional $f((x_n))=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n $

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

> Define $f((x_n))=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n) $ for all $(x_n) \in  c$ then show that $f$  continuous and find $\vert \vert f \vert \vert?$

My thought $\vert f((x_n)) \vert \leq\lim  \sup x_n \leq \vert \vert x_n \vert \vert_{\infty}$. How can I proof other way around?

Comment: which norm are you using?

Comment: Sorry for that, Supremum   norm.

Comment: Then see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

$||f||=\sup _{||x_n||=1} f(x_n)=\sup_{||x_n=1} \lim x_n$

Now since $||x_n||=1\implies \max_{n\in \Bbb N} |x_n|=1\implies \lim x_n\le 1$

So $||f||\le 1$

On the other hand take the sequence $(x_n)=(1,1,1,\ldots )$

then $f(x_n)=1\implies ||f||\ge1$

Hence,combining $||f||=1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\vert f((x_n)) \vert=\vert \lim x_n\vert
 \leq\sup| x_n |= \vert \vert x_n \vert \vert$$
Then

$$\| f \|=  \sup_{\vert \vert x_n \vert \vert=1} \vert f((x_n)) \vert \leq1$$
Now taking the Constant sequence $x_n=1$ we get 
$$1\ge  \| f \|\ge
\vert f((x_n)) \vert =1= \sup| x_n| = \vert \vert x_n \vert \vert$$

Hence 
$$\| f \|=1$$

Comment: Isn't this the same as mine?